# can't cast LaunchViewController to UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, casting, reachability

I am trying to check the network status from the AppDelegate.swift instead of checking from LaunchViewController.

I have written `showOfflinePage` in `AppDelegate` when I shut down my network I have this error cast

> Could not cast value of type
>   'reachability_playground.LaunchViewController' (0x1095b5f20) to
>   'UINavigationController' (0x114bb2a20). 2019-01-06
>   16:42:04.079430-0500 reachability-playground[2781:93635] Could not
>   cast value of type 'reachability_playground.LaunchViewController'
>   (0x1095b5f20) to 'UINavigationController' (0x114bb2a20).

```
   private func showOfflinePage() -> Void {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
            let viewController: LaunchViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LaunchViewController") as! LaunchViewController;

            // Then push that view controller onto the navigation stack
            let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
            rootViewController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the exception message, your root view controller is an instance of `LaunchViewController`, not an instance of `UINavigationController` so the forced downcast fails.

You need to check your storyboard and ensure that the entry point scene is a navigation controller.